# ModelAttribute Doesn't return any value from front end to back end

Tags: spring, thymeleaf, modelattribute

I'm using spring boot and thymeleaf to create a form to collect the data from front-end and update the database at back-end. I'm having trouble to pass the object value by using ModelAttribute. I can almost guaranty my repository and my bean work fine because I have written Junit test case against it and I can see the update from DB. I tried to use th:field at the html page, but it doesn't give me any default value in the field, so I have to use th:value. The print out statements in the controller just keep return 0. It feels like (@ModelAttribute("city") CityBean city) just never pass any data into the variable city. I can't really tell where the problem is after hours of the debugging. I will attach my code here. Thank you very much for helping.

My bean:

```
public class CityBean {
int cityID;
int population;
String cityName;
String state;
```

My Repository/DAO:

```
    public int updatePopulation(CityBean city) {
    String sql = "UPDATE CITY SET population = ? WHERE cityID = ?";
    Object[] args = {city.getPopulation(), city.getCityID()};
    int[] types = {Types.VARCHAR, Types.INTEGER};

    return jdbcTemplate.update(sql, args, types);
}
```

My controller:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/action", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String updatePopulation(@ModelAttribute("city") CityBean city) {

    System.out.println("This is city ID " + city.getCityID());
    System.out.println("This is city population " + city.getPopulation());

    cityRepository.updatePopulation(city);

    return "redirect:/cityInfo";
}
```

My Front-end HTML:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>CS6400 Fall 2020 Team 017 Project</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-TX8t27EcRE3e/ihU7zmQxVncDAy5uIKz4rEkgIXeMed4M0jlfIDPvg6uqKI2xXr2" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>
<body>
<h1 style="text-align:center">City Population Update Form</h1>
<br>
<form action="#" th:action="@{/action}" th:object="${city}" method="post" modelAttribute="city">
    >
<table class="table">
    <thead>
    <tr>
        <th scope="col">City ID</th>
        <th scope="col">City Name</th>
        <th scope="col">State</th>
        <th scope="col">Population</th>
        <th scope="col">Action</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    <tr >
        <td><input type="text=" th:value="*{cityID}" readonly="readonly"></td>
        <td><input type="text=" th:value="*{cityName}" readonly="readonly"></td>
        <td><input type="text=" th:value="*{state}" readonly="readonly"></td>
        <td><input type="text=" th:value="*{population}" ></td>
        <td>
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Update Population</button>
        </td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
</form>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: If you want values remove the `readonly` part. It means exactly that, `readonly`. and use `th:field` instead of `th:object`.

Comment: Thank you for replying, I take off the readonly and change it to th:field, but still doesn't work. Do you have another suggestion?

Comment: I assume you have the appropriate getter and setters?

Comment: Yes I do, I also have the appropriate  mapper for the getter and setters. If I tried to manually set the value in the controller by using setters, my db will be updated normally. I think the problem is I’m not able to get the data(city object) passed from the html to the controller for some reason

Comment: WHen do you want to see this? Before or after the submit? If it is after it won't work because you are using a redirect.

Comment: It should be seem after the submit. I'm redirecting back to the cityInfo page which is a page that pulls all the data about cities and populations from DB. If the it updated successfully, I should be able to see the new population in the cityInfo page.

Comment: If you redirect to the same page it won't work as the model will e cleared. It basically is just a get to that page, which I assume creates a new model in your controller.

Comment: I tried to return to the same page, unfortunately, the issue remains the same. The  (@ModelAttribute("city") CityBean city) is not return the object value to the back end.

Comment: Problem solved, I added name="pramName" in the input tag then everything works fine. Thank you so much for providing the suggestion.

Comment: You shouldn't need the `name` attribute on you rinput tags, that should be handled by using `th:field` instead of `th:value`.

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved, I added name="pramName" in the input tag then everything works fine.